# "Case label value has already appeared in this switch" when no duplicate cases can be found

Tags: c++

I am working on programming the game 2048 in C++ as an exercise to get familiar with the language. Originally, the code wasn't throwing any errors but I was getting some logic errors in the final product so I thought that the problem could be that I was using the logic gates incorrectly. I looked it up and apparently the correct syntax for or was `||` when I was only using `|`, after I changed all of them to `||` my switch statement started saying that there were duplicate cases when it doesnt seem like there are any. what could this be caused by?

```
void slide(char direction){
    int i;
    int j;
    switch (direction){
        case 'W' || 'w':
            for (j = 0; j < boardSize; j++){
                int firstZero = -1;
                for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i++){
                    if (board[i][j] == 0 && firstZero < 0){
                        firstZero = i;
                    }
                    if (board[i][j] > 0 && firstZero >= 0){
                        int temp = board[i][j];
                        board[i][j] = board[firstZero][j];
                        board[firstZero][j] = temp;
                        if (i != boardSize-1){
                            i = 0;
                            firstZero = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        break;
        case 'A' || 'a':
        break;
        case 'S' || 's':
        break;
        case 'D' || 'd':
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `case 'A' || 'a'` should work? What does your favourite C++ book say about `switch-case`? It's not a good idea to write programs by guessing the language rules.

Comment: You can't do "alternative" cases like that.  `'A' || 'a'` is evaluated, by the usual behavior of the `||` operator, to the constant integer `1` (since its operands are not both zero).  So you effectively have a whole bunch of `case 1:` in your program, and the compiler is correct in saying there are duplicate cases.

Comment: `'W'||'w'` is `true`. `'A'||'a'` is `true`. etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look toward this approach:

```
case 'A': // If it is A, fall through 
case 'a': // If it is a, pick this case
    // Do something
    break;
// Other cases...
```

This way, the choice will fall through.

On why your form of the condition does not work:

> Condition - any expression of integral or enumeration type, or of a
> class type contextually implicitly convertible to an integral or
> enumeration type, or a declaration of a single non-array variable of
> such type with a brace-or-equals initializer. - [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch)

A condition should evaluate to the value that is equal to the value of one of the **constant_expressions** on which it is tested on. This leads to the situation where the `||` is not evaluated as you expect; all the clauses evaluated to `1` *(since both `A` and `a` aren't zero)*, hence the multiple cases are the same.

**Bottom line**: `case` label must be an [integral constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Integral_constant_expression).